# How to redirect to different routes depending on role in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm new to Symfony2 and subsequently the FOSUserBundle. I understand what the bundle is and what to use it for but I have questions on how to use the bundle to become associated with my views and controllers that are already in place.

I have already set up the bundle and have it working but I am confused on my next quest.

The Setup: On the login page for the FOSUserBundle, I want to have 'admin users' routed to a certain page and 'normal users' routed to a different one. Where do I place this logic? I currently have it in the DefaultController for my bundle but get page: `localhost isn't working...localhost redirected you too many times...` I cleared cache but still same result.

DefaultController:

```
namespace Pas\ShopTestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {   

        if ('admin_login' === $request->get('_route')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('product'); //just test to product
        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login'); //just test to login
        }

    }
}
```

Now my ULTIMATE goal is once the users have logged in, have their username show on the page they have been sent to. How do I code that? Where does it go?

I would really appreciate the help, thank you all.

Symfony 2.7 : FOSUserBundle 2.0

EDIT: security.yml

```
security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:  ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_NORMAL: ROLE_NORMAL

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /

            logout:     true
            anonymous:  true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/admin_login, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: What is normal user? Is it authenticated user or just an anonymous user? What is 'admin_login'? Why would you test for 'admin_login' route inside `default/index`? Can you provide us with the security.yml, specifically the ones about access control? I think your redirect happens because your are already logged in, so the app redirects you to `default/index` and your condition is never met ('admin_login' != _route), so it redirects it back to login. And this loops forever, which eventually gives you too many redirects ever.

Comment: I made an edit with the security.yml. and normal user is an anonymous authenticated user. I see your point too...Where else/should I test for admin_login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem. The route at the indexAction is `/`. Your condition inside the indexAction basically gets interpreted as this: "Does the current route, which is always `/` because it is called from inside this route, equal to `admin_login`?" That's why your condition always returns false.

With that logic, the route `/` always redirects to route `login`. And the route `login` always redirects to `/` because role for login is `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` but you are already authenticated (which means your current role is either `ROLE_NORMAL` or `ROLE_ADMIN`).

EDIT: Now that I read your comment update, you only need to add the path to access control:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/product$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and do something like the following to default/index:

```
function indexAction() {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('product');
}
```

EDIT2: If your indexAction doesn't do anything other than redirect to route `product`, you can remove the controller and add the following to routing.yml:

```
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: product
        permanent: true
```

[Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html)

Comment: ahhh perfect, thanks so much! Would it be too much to ask if you could help me with my 'ultimate goal' problem as well? I'm confused on how to make this bundle interact with my other controllers and views (I haven't found anything good through the documentation)

Comment: Check out the documentations for [Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) and [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html). Think of FOSUserBundle as a backend for symfony user manager. You only use the bundle if you need to create user, find user by id etc, while you use security for authorizing the user's role, getting the currently logged in user etc.

Answer (score 5):

or you can do it like this with:

adding this to your main firewall in security.yml

```
main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: acme_user.login_success_handler


        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

and creating the according service in services.xml

```
<services>
    <service id="acme_user.login_success_handler" class="Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginSuccessHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="router" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
        <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="security"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

And then for the LoginSuccessHandler.php class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') || $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin_route'));
        } else {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_route'));
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```